# Black screen with two monitors, but works with three monitors

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, multi-monitor

I have a *very* strange problem with my monitor setup. I have a laptop with an Nvidia RTX 2070 GPU and a 1920x1080 240Hz LCD panel. I have two identical external monitors connected (2560x1440 60Hz), one directly to an HDMI port and the other to USB-C through a dongle (recognized as DisplayPort by Linux). X configuration with all three monitors works without problems, but when I disable the laptop panel then one of the two monitors shows a black screen with a message that says that the "current input timing is not supported by the display", even though it's set to monitor's native 2560x1440@60Hz, which is exactly the same as with the 3-monitor configuration that works.

The same 2-monitor setup works without problems in Windows, and it used to work a little over a year ago in Linux on this very machine with these same monitors (it's even the same Linux installation). I only used the laptop panel for the last few months so I'm not sure when exactly it stopped working. There were also one or two BIOS updates during that time, but that wouldn't explain why 3-monitor configuration works (and Windows too in a 2-m setup). I *suspect* that it has something to do with the fact that the laptop screen is 240Hz and that something goes wrong there, but I have no way of verifying which display mode is actually sent to the monitor.

The OS is a fully up-to-date Arch Linux. I'm using proprietary Nvidia drivers from the official Arch repos. I also tried the LTS kernel and corresponding Nvidia modules but no joy. Nouveau is blacklisted through a kernel parameter and the laptop is configured in BIOS to only use the discreet GPU, so no hybrid graphics, Optimus or similar.

Comment: the recently released gnome 3.38 indeed did some things on [multi-monitor support](https://blogs.gnome.org/shell-dev/2020/07/02/splitting-up-the-frame-clock/) but this does only affect wayland-sessions and you have nvidia so I assume you still have X? and what desktop-environment are you using? Maybe you can try wayland with nvidia under gnome, I got it running on fedora 32 (until I gave up because sleep didn't work so I bought a radeon)

Comment: @blaimi Yes, I don't use Wayland due to Nvidia, I disabled it in GDM and Gnome session.